# How many objects will be created when using only "new" operator in JAVA?

Tags: java, new-operator

I have read the documentation, but some says it creates two objects, some says it creates one object only.

In interviews these things are asked frequently, I don't know what to say and explain how I got the answer.

How many `String` objects will be created when we write only this statement?

```
public class Test123 {
    String st = new String();
}
```

Comment: [Creating objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) - search for `java new` in your search engine of choice.

Comment: `new String()` will create a single object.  The only way more than one `String` object might be created is if you used `String` concatenation within a loop, as generally, the compiler is smart enough to convert general `String` concatenation to use a `StringBuilder` (internally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero.  `st` will only be assigned to when an instance of `Test123` is created, and nothing ever does that.

Comment: are you sure no object is created according to OP.

Comment: No, but I am sure no object is created according to me, given the code in the OP.

Comment: @recursive- do you mean zero object because no string literals are assigned to it ?

Comment: @recursive well, you're wrong! The code above **does** create a new object with a distinct address in memory (on the heap). Try: `String s1 = new String(); String s2 = new String(); System.out.println(s1 == s2);` it'll print `false` - cause the objects are not the same! For more info - see my answer below.

Comment: @alfasin: Those statements only create objects on the heap if they are executed.  Putting an initializer in a class that is never instantiated is not enough to execute the code.  In order for that code to execute, an instance of `Test123` has to be created.

Comment: @NinadPingale: No, string literals have nothing to do with it.  A class declaration doesn't actually create an instance of anything.

Comment: @recursive this is a "wise-ass" reasoning but still true. I'll edit your answer in order to change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @alfasin: If I could guess what the "real" question was, I'd answer it.  The next best thing is technical correctness.  Perhaps the OP will clarify.

Comment: @recursive The real question is that **How many objects will be created when we write this line?**
`String st= new String();`

Comment: @user3921124 to continue recursive's wissass approach - when you write the line nothing happens. When this line is **ran** then only one single object is being created. Why would you expect more than one object to be created ?

Comment: The only possible argument I can think of for any number other than **1**, is someone might believe that the JVM has a special case for aggressively interning empty strings.

Comment: @alfasin Okay. Got it. An explanation was given to me as **When u write a "new" operator it creates a new object in heap memory and in the pool too.**

Comment: No, it will create only one object on the heap. If you'll call String.intern()( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) later on, it will create a copy of the string in the string-pool (assuming it doesn't already exist there) and return a reference to it.

Answer (score 5):

When you creating the String object using

```
String s = new String(“xyz”) it will create two objects.
```

1. The **first object** will be created in java permanent heap memory as part of the argument we are passing - "XYZ" . and it will be **created in String Literal Pool**.
2. **Second object** will be **created within java heap memory** - which will be created as part of new operator.

Comment: Hi @Sachin, if you create a String using the 'new' keyword, it isn't interned unless you explicitly call .intern(); Therefore the String 's' won't be added to the String Pool as written in your example as far as I know because you aren't interning it.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with String literals. **Every** call to `new` creates one new object on the heap.

When you do something like:

```
String st = "something";
```

the string "something" is looked-up in the String-pool, if it doesn't exist - it will be added to the pool and a reference to it will be returned. If it already exists - a reference to it will be returned.
This has nothing to do with the `new` keyword, and there isn't *any* scenario in which you'll create two Strings with a single `new` command.

Comment: Why do you bring up `String` literals? Your second sentence is the only relevant piece.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I brought it up as a response to Ruchira's answer above as well as to make sure to clear any confusion the OP/others might have with the way string literals and string-pool works in Java.

Comment: From my standpoint, you're causing more confusion by bringing up concepts that OP may not have read about yet.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the only reason this question deals with `String` and not with any other kind of object is the String-pool. People love to ask about it in interviews because this is a subject that most people don't bother to inquire and fully understand (even though it's not complicated) - as a proof - see the answers and comments here... I don't think that my answer creates more confusion but if it does I'll be glad to change the wording or explain in more details points that are still unclear in my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`new` operation only creates **one object**.

But it's parameter is a `String`, which already represents an `object`. So any time you use a `String` it is implicitly create an `object`.

Comment: Why do you bring up `String` literals?

Comment: Your last sentence is vague - what do you mean by "any time you use String" ?

Comment: @Ruchira So is there a difference when I use String as a parameter?